# I have a button that is not clickable and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

this is part of a form button one is signup and another one is an "already have an account" button. both are not clickable. I played around with z-index, added href for redirect on already have an account button, I have a hash action on the form. nothing is happening at all. here is my Jade/Pug code. The last three lines on the code contain my button

```
 form(action='#', role='form')
              .form-group
                strong USERNAME
                | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                .input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-user
                  | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                  input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Username')
              | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
              .form-group
                strong EMAIL
                | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                .input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-envelope
                  | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                  input.form-control(type='email', placeholder='Email')
              | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
              .form-group
                strong PASSWORD
                | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                .input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-lock
                  | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                  input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password')
              | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
              .form-group.text-center
                button.btn.btn-dark.btn-lg(type='submit') Signup
                | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
                a.btn.btn-link(href='/' style='z-index:10') Already Have an Account
```

Comment: Can you show us the resulting HTML?

Comment: i uploaded it on my school's hosting  http://triosdevelopers.com/~R.Epistola/nodewireframe/signup.html
I am currently making the signup/login logic on nodejs and i can't move forward without sorting this out. Thank you for looking

Comment: Remember that `z-index` only works on positioned elements (absolute, relative, fixed,...)

Comment: It seems that one of your `<div class="container">` is overlaying the form and buttons.

Comment: how could i miss that! Thank you sir. added a bootstrap row class to avoid the overlap. please submit an answer on this so i could verify your answer. Thank you